# Deno Slow FS Performance

Tags: javascript, deno

I've noticed a very noticeably slow performance in reading files in deno, I'm afraid I might be doing it wrong. (kinda stupid?)

```
const file = Deno.readFileSync(path)
```

any suggestions? or other faster ways?
should I use `Deno.run` instead? what are the pros and cons of `Deno.run` in your experience?

**Update #1:**

I found [this module](https://deno.land/manual@v1.19.0/examples/unix_cat) using streams in which it give some more speed, but compared to bash it's very slow:

```
$ time deno run --allow-read https://deno.land/std@0.126.0/examples/cat.ts movie.mp4 |  wc -l
4066379

real    0m1.890s
user    0m1.608s
sys     0m1.355s

$ time cat movie.mp4 | wc -l
4066379

real    0m0.295s
user    0m0.098s
sys     0m0.372s

$ du -sh movie.mp4 
995M    movie.mp4
```

**Update #2:**

Due to the worries of the network speed and Deno launch speed, I made this script where it has them both running respectively:

```js
import {
  copy,
  writeAllSync,
} from "https://deno.land/std@0.126.0/streams/conversion.ts";

const filenames = "movie.mp4";

//########## DENO ############

const before1 = performance.now();

const file = await Deno.open(filenames);
await copy(file, Deno.stdout);
file.close();

const after1 = performance.now() - before1;

const text1 = new TextEncoder().encode(after1.toString() + "\n");
writeAllSync(Deno.stderr, text1);

//########## CMD ############

const before2 = performance.now();

const p = Deno.run({
  cmd: ["cat", `${filenames}`],
});

await p.status()

const after2 = performance.now() - before2;

const text2 = new TextEncoder().encode(after2.toString() + "\n");
writeAllSync(Deno.stderr, text2);
```

Results in best case:

```
$ deno run --allow-run --allow-read test.ts >/dev/null
636
82
```

Comment: have you tried using `Deno.readFile` instead of `Deno.readFileSync`… I'm not sure using the asynchronous method should perform much differently but JavaScript by nature an asynchronous language and given support now for top-level `await` I suggest using that whenever possible

Comment: There might be some beneficials doing that, just not on the performance side, using `Deno.readFile` Is just moving the sync to the upper level of the call stack, where we will end up with the same result awaiting it with same speed.

Comment: I found [this](https://deno.land/manual@v1.19.0/examples/unix_cat) in which it might give the speed I'm looking for using streams, however, I need to look into it a little more. (still slow, but I will investigate)

Comment: You're reading a remote file, so that includes a highly variable network time and also timing the entire command which includes initializing deno aren't you?...

Comment: yep! you're right, you have mentioned network speed, and deno launch time, and that does effect the performance, I moved all to `ts` file, so we will not worry about the launch time, and deno usually caches the code, however, for consistency I placed them both in the same script, you can find it in an update to the question.

Comment: What's the actual question? How you want to process the files' data has a huge impact on how you should strategy reading them. If you can show that code, this question becomes more actionable. (Also, in your updated example, you are not [waiting for the `cat` subprocess to exit](https://deno.land/manual@v1.19.0/examples/subprocess) before marking the end time.)

Comment: Ah, you got a good point @jsejcksn I knew something was wron with the run statement, still the speed is too slow in comparison, please have a look at the update.

Comment: The code is basically about reading a file, then making a checksum, the checksum isn't a problem, but the slowspeed of the read is bugging me.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I will be reading files in huge amount, so speed matter.

Answer (score 0):

Until this moment of writing this comment, I'd like to mention there are no solutions regarding this well-known issue in deno.

There are multiple opened issues in denoland/deno Repository. If there are any updates, I will post an update.

To mention few:

[#13720](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/13720)

[#10157](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/10157)

[#803](https://github.com/denoland/deno_std/issues/803)

[#246](https://github.com/oakserver/oak/issues/246)

[#13608](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/13608)

If you find any, please let me know.

Thanks.